# Oracle AQ set message state to EXPIRED

Tags: oracle, plsql, advanced-queuing

Is is possible to set message state to `DBMS_AQ.EXPIRED` without reaching `retry_count`?

From oracle documentation `dbms_aq.message_properties_t.state`:

> Specifies the state of the message at the time of the dequeue. This
> parameter cannot be set at enqueue time. The possible states follow:
>
> - DBMS_AQ.READY: The message is ready to be processed.
> - DBMS_AQ.WAITING: The message delay has not yet been reached.
> - DBMS_AQ.PROCESSED: The message has been processed and is retained.
> - DBMS_AQ.EXPIRED: The message has been moved to the exception queue.

However when i try to dequeue message with `state := DBMS_AQ.EXPIRED` it's state after dequeue is still `DBMS_AQ.PROCESSED`.

```
declare
    procedure mark_as_expired(p_queue_name in varchar2, p_msgid in raw) is
        l_dequeue_options DBMS_AQ.DEQUEUE_OPTIONS_T;
        l_message_properties DBMS_AQ.MESSAGE_PROPERTIES_T;

        l_dummy_payload obj_dummy;
        l_dummy_msgid raw(16);
    begin
        l_dequeue_options.msgid := p_msgid;
        l_dequeue_options.wait := DBMS_AQ.NO_WAIT;
        l_dequeue_options.navigation := DBMS_AQ.FIRST_MESSAGE;

        l_message_properties.state := DBMS_AQ.EXPIRED;

        dbms_aq.dequeue(
            queue_name => sys_context('USERENV', 'CURRENT_USER')||'.'||p_queue_name,
            dequeue_options => l_dequeue_options,
            message_properties => l_message_properties,
            payload => l_dummy_payload,
            msgid => l_dummy_msgid);
    end;
begin
    mark_as_expired('QUEUE_NAME', 'BE3228C90B3239BBE0534980CB0AE63E');
end;
```

Comment: Can't understand which problem you are solving.
If you know you messages are bad, then just dequeue them (sometimes not that simple, but possbile).
And, secondly, how does second part, with "PROCESSED" state, relates to initial problem?

Comment: Problem is that you might know that message is bad at execution time, when some request is invokes, but not after. And sometimes you might know that further processing of the same message result will be the same. So you want to dequeue them. My question was if a message can be dequeued in a way, that MSG_STATE after dequeue would be EXPIRED and not PROCESSED. So it would reflect that message haven't been processed successfully. Also we have a retention mechanism on QUEUE, so moving message to EXCEPTION QUEUE will retain that message, and might help in debugging past problems.

Comment: In short: you want message to be moved to exception queue after just one exception during processing? If so, then look at `max_retries` parameter in `DBMS_AQADM.CREATE_QUEUE`. Anyway, making logic on `state` field is no good, you need to find better way.